# Re-Train huggingface pre trained model properly

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, huggingface-transformers

I have a hugginface model, I am re-training it after adding a few layers of my own.

```
embedding = model(input_ids, attention_mask=input_mask)[0]

embedding = tf.layers.Embedding(tokenizer.vocab_size, 256, input_length=max_len)(embedding)

out = tf.layers.LSTM(50,return_sequences=True)(embedding)
out = tf.layers.Dropout(.2)(out)

out = tf.layers.Bidirectional(tf.layers.LSTM(10,return_sequences=True))(out)
out = tf.layers.Dropout(.2)(out)

out = tf.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(out)
out = tf.layers.Dropout(.2)(out)

out = tf.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(out)

new_model = tf.Model(inputs=[input_ids,input_mask], outputs=out)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(
learning_rate=.01,
epsilon=.01,
decay=.1,
clipnorm=1.0
)
loss = tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

new_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss=loss,metrics=metric)
```

Now when I run model.fit with training and validation data i get this runtime error

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._0/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._1/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._2/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._3/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._4/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._5/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._6/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._7/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._8/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._9/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._10/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/encoder/layer_._11/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/embeddings/word_embeddings/weight:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/embeddings/token_type_embeddings/embeddings:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/embeddings/position_embeddings/embeddings:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/embeddings/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/roberta/embeddings/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/classifier/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/classifier/dense/bias:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/classifier/out_proj/kernel:0', 'tf_roberta_for_sequence_classification/classifier/out_proj/bias:0'] when minimizing the loss. If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss`argument?
```

What am I doing wrong. Also can someone explain what does this error actually means to say?

Also even after 3 epochs the accuracy is not improving.

Please help me on how to re-train a pre trained model with transfer learning I am very new to this.

Comment: how do you create the initial model?

Comment: @BerkayBerabi Its a huggingface pre-trained model. loaded using transformer.TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained()

Comment: i mostly use pytroch so not an expert on tensorflow but it looks strange to me that you take the model with the classification head. Essentially, you want to add new layers to your model and finally your own head. You should take the bare model without any head that outputs raw embeddings. Can you try with model = transformers.TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained(...)

Comment: @BerkayBerabi actually I had used ```transformer.TFRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained()```. Can you please elaborate on what does classification head mean? isn't this ```model(input_ids, attention_mask=input_mask)[0]``` giving me the raw embedding that you talking about? What I want to do is use the output weights from the model and then further train my own layers to give me a classification model trained on my own data.